# jFlex error: class throws java.io.IOException

Tags: java, lexical-analysis, jflex

I have written a very simple file with specification shown below to to tokenize words:

```
%%
%class Lexer
%unicode

WORD = [^\r\n\t ]

%%
{WORD}  {System.out.println("Word is:"+yytext());}

.       {System.out.println("Bad character: "+ yytext());}
```

The following are the commands I run:

```
jflex hindi.jlex
javac Lexer.java
```

I get the following error:

```
Lexer.java:442: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class Yytoken
location: class Lexer
  public Yytoken yylex() throws java.io.IOException {
     ^
1 error
```

Any help appreciated.

On a additional note I checked the `Lexer.java` file and there was no `main` function in it. Is that the reason for this error.

Comment: I removed the `antlr` tag, since I fail to see how it is related to ANTLR.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to check the lexer standalone(without a parser) then add the following to the user code section:

```
%standalone
```

Answer (score 1):

Those working with byaccj and getting this error should add a `%byaccj` line instead of `%standalone` below the `%class Lexer` line